# Defining and overriding open and closed intervals

Tags: terminology

I have been considering the following situation as part of documenting and interface (`A`) and an implementation (`B`) of that interface.

The interface `A` contains methods which involve the following two arguments:

1. A *percentage*, passed as an integer.
2. A *name*, passed as a string.

The valid values for the *percentage* are the closed range [0, 100]. No matter how you implement the interface, it is an error to allow a value outside this range as an input.

The *name*, as defined in the interface, allows any string containing [1, 100] characters. I want to document the interface in such a way that it neither *requires* nor *disallows* an implementation to support a *name* with more than 100 characters.

Clearly the valid range for *percentage* is a closed, inclusive interval. **How would you refer to a range like I defined above for the number of characters in *name*?** I can't refer to the interval as right-open, because the implementation might not support values with more than 100 characters.

Comment: @Dukeling can you remove that comment and add it as an answer?

Comment: Added as an answer, with a bit more ... stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a specific name for it, you'll probably have to write it out, e.g.:

> The minimum length of `name` must be 1. There is no strict maximum length, but any implementation must support a maximum length of at least 100.

This is more concise, although somewhat less clear:

> Any implementation must support a minimum length of `name` of 1 and a maximum of at least 100.

You can also write:

> Any implementation must support the length of `name` in the range `[1,x]`, with `x >= 100` (`x` is chosen by the implementation).

Which is similar to your comment in the [question on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14297/defining-and-overriding-open-and-closed-intervals?noredirect=1#comment30371_14297) which was lost in the merge.

It might also be a good idea to add this to any / all of the above:

> ... and throw a YouNeedToRenameThis exception when outside this range.